# Adding a string in context menu using for statement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-context, android-contextmenu

Hi I'm trying to put a string(class prices) in a context menu. But my code is not returning as I expected. Can someone help me to solve this?

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
         super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
         menu.setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.display_title));  
         //menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, getString(R.string.display_schedule_ticket_prices)); 

         StringBuilder pricesAlert = new StringBuilder("");
            //int i = 0;
         for(float price: rates.getPrices()){
             for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            pricesAlert.append(getString(R.string.display_schedule_train_class) + j + getString(R.string.display_schedule_train_rs) +  price +"\r\n");
            menu.add(pricesAlert);
             }
         } 
     }
```

**Edited:**

I'm getting the results something like this using above code.
[image]

But I want the output like this:
[image]

Comment: is the context menu showing up? what is it displaying?

Comment: yap it's showing the list of price for class 1,2 & 3 in a context menu. But the way I loop is wrong.

Comment: i'm not getting you, are you saying that nothing is happening after selecting one option?

Comment: Please describe what is the expected outcome. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @ Metalhead1247 & Chiral Code: I edited my post. Please see above. And rates.getPrices() is the object to call the prices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet

```
 @Override  
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");  
menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");  
}  

 @Override  
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    if(item.getTitle()=="Action 1"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
else if(item.getTitle()=="Action 2"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
else {return false;}  
return true;  
 }
```

Is this what you want to do? refer http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/

have you added actions to your context menu?

Comment: yap. I already checked that link. But I want to add a json object as a context menu list. **rates.getPrices()**